# How to split large frames

Tags: jasper-reports

I've a jasper-report that has a detail band with the height of 1500px. My page height is 842px. There is a frame with the height of 940px inside this band.
Here is my jrxml-File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2016-08-04T11:33:30 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
name="Template" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="fe0ec478-f3f0-4324-9feb-f143cc73c90f">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record" />
  <detail>
    <band height="1500" splitType="Stretch">
      <frame>
        <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="30" width="555" height="940" backcolor="#F5F9FF" uuid="917a9ec0-b801-49ca-93e7-5106f89868e9">
          <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel" />
        </reportElement>
        <box>
          <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#E3E3E3" />
        </box>
      </frame>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30" uuid="303bc3ed-22ad-4f01-a7d1-c35e8b95ac77" />
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Static Text]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
    </band>
  </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

After compilation I get following error:

```
The detail section, the page and column headers and footers and the margins do not fit the page height. --- net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign
```

My first question is: why do I get this exception?

If I change the Split Type of the detail band to "Immediate" then I do not get the above error any more. After a few minutes I get OutOfMemoryError.
My third question: why do i get this error after changing the Split Type to "Immediate".

My third question is: how can i split my frame into 772px (after StaticText) and 168px on the top of the next page? I would like to display multiple Frames (with different heights; some of them very long) one after another.

Comment: The height of Detail band is bigger than report's pageHeight: 1500 > (842 - 40), where 40 is the sum of both margins

Comment: `After a few minutes I get OutOfMemoryError.` - this is a bug of JSS

Comment: `how can i split my frame into 772px (after StaticText) and 168px on the top of the next page?` - You can use pagenbreak and several Detail bands

Comment: But if I change the heigth of the detail band to 802, then my large frame will not fit in it and I will get "Warning : Element bottom reaches outside band area : y=30 height=940 band-height=802". That's why I set the bandHeigth to 1500px.
Is the pagebreak and several detail bands the only possibility to display multiple blocks e.g. frames (with different heights) one after another?

Comment: At this point I can calculate the required Height for my frames (depending on elements that will be put in this block/frame) and required height of the detail band (the number of blocks/frames + margins) dynamically based on some external information. There is no problem when: frameHeight < (pageHeight - marginTop - marginBottom). The detail band is always bigger then the 802. And that works. The problem appears only if the frameHeight > (pageHeight - marginTop - marginBottom). Is there any split-option for frames that will work in my case?

Answer (score 2):

you must change template size to your heigh
page size -> page heigh

try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Template" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="1600" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.610510000000001"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="1500" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="30" width="555" height="940" backcolor="#F5F9FF">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#E3E3E3"/>
                </box>
            </frame>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[
          Static Text
        ]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

if you split page u can use:

```
<break><reportElement x="0" y="10" width="100" height="1"/></break>
```

page break in your report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Template" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="1600" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.610510000000001"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="1500" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="84" width="555" height="886" backcolor="#F5F9FF">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#E3E3E3"/>
                </box>
            </frame>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[firtst page]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="43" width="555" height="30"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[next page]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <break>
                <reportElement x="0" y="33" width="100" height="1"/>
            </break>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: What is `template size`?

Comment: beacause your detail band height of 1500px and pageHeight  842px, but page heigh must bigger than band height. In the ireport this setting is in template propertis.

Comment: @user3782729: this is not exactly what I want. The Height of my page must be 842. 
I would like to display multiple Blocks e.g. Frames (with different heights; some of them very long) one after another on the pages with the height of 842.

Comment: @user3782729: could you please show me in my example, how can I use <break>-Element?

Comment: @user3782729: tahnk you. But as I wrote, the heigth of my pages must be 842px.